# The method '[]' was called on null. even value should be there

Tags: flutter, dart

I am querying from a SQLite database and assigning that response to a `_user` variable. Because this is immutable I am then creating a new variable and setting that data to it as shown in the SQLite for Flutter package docs. I am doing this in the `initState` to ensure that this is happening before the `build` method executes which relies on this data. However, I am getting the following error when I first go to the screen that executes this

```
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("firstName")
```

I'm not really sure what I am doing wrong here since the `initState` method should be executing before the `build` method and thus the necessary data should be there

Here's my code:

```
static Map<String, dynamic> _user;
Map<String, dynamic> newUser;


@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setupUser();
    print('initState : newUser: $newUser'); // Print 1
}


setupUser() async {
    _user = await DBProvider.db.getUser();
    Map<String, dynamic> newUser = Map<String, dynamic>.from(_user);

    print('initState : setupUser : newUser: $newUser'); // Print 2
}


Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: ...,
        body: Container(
            child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                    ...
                    TextField(
                        controller: TextEditingController(text: newUser['firstName']),
                        onChanged: (text) {
                            setState(() {
                                newUser['firstName'] = text;
                            });
                        },
                    ),
                    ...
                ],
            ),
        ),
    ),
}
```

**EDIT:**
If I set `Map<String, dynamic> newUser;` to initially have a value of `{}` the error goes away, however the data does not show in the TextField unit I tap into the field, suggesting that the `build` method is actually running before the `_user` is assigned to `newUser`. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit 2**
Also for what it's worth `print 1` shows that `newUser` is `{}` while `print 2` shows that `newUser` is equal to what it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in initState asycn function not wait before build stage.
So your app call build widget before _user recieve data from DBProvider. AKA asycn function not work in initState.

You should try Future builder like this

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    appBar: ...,
    body: Container(
        child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
                ...
                FutureBuilder(
                  future: DBProvider.db.getUser(),
                  builder: (_,userDataSnapshot){
                     Map<String, dynamic> newUser = userDataSnapshot.data,
                     return TextField(
                        controller: TextEditingController(text: newUser['firstName']),
                        onChanged: (text) {
                           setState(() {
                            newUser['firstName'] = text;
                            });
                         },
                      ),
                     },
                ),
                ...
            ],
        ),
    ),
),
}
```

PS. you can use one variable

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are redeclaring `newUser` in the scope of `setupUser`. You should not declare the variable again but only assign it:

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> newUser = Map<String, dynamic>.from(_user);
```

You need to turn the above into this:

```dart
newUser = Map<String, dynamic>.from(_user);
```

The way you did it, the assigned `newUser` variable lives only inside of `initState`. Removing the type at the beginning makes it so that you do not have a declaration anymore but only an assignment to the `newUser` variable in the whole class.

Comment: Make perfect sense but doesn't work, when I restart the app I have the same error

Comment: @Garrett I did not see that you were calling an `async` function. Any asynchronous code will finish after `initState`, i.e. after `build` - no matter how fast it is.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you're thinking of "initState is called before build", that's not actually the case.  Your initState here contains async calls, and thus build may also be called before those async calls are complete.  You'll need to check if the data is actually alive before accessing it.